# Enabling Shipping Method (via observer)

Tags: event-observer, shipping-methods

Lets say I want to check what shipping methods are available (before customer sees the shipping methods) and want to enable one if certain conditions exist.

- What event would I be observing
- What method calls do I need:

  1. To see what shipping methods are enabled
  2. To enable a given shipping method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento  shipping method is `depends on shipping address` .
first load quote `shipping address then  get shipping method from shipping address` and code should like this

```
 $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if(!is_null($quoteShippingAddress->getId()) ) {

 $quoteShippingAddress->collectShippingRates()->save();
     $groupedRates = $quoteShippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
            $ratesResult = array();
            foreach ($groupedRates as $carrierCode => $rates ) {
                $carrierName = $carrierCode;
                if (!is_null(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title'))) {
                    $carrierName = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title');
                }

                foreach ($rates as $rate) {
                    $rateItem = $this->_getAttributes($rate, "quote_shipping_rate");
                    $rateItem['carrierName'] = $carrierName;
                    $ratesResult[] = $rateItem;
                    unset($rateItem);
                }
            }

}
```

**$result is give shipping method list**

2.As amasty say,`shipping method are enabled from admin`.Also you can do this by  programmatically:

```
 $groups=array();
shippimgmethodcode='freeshipping';
$groups[$shippimgmethodcode][fields][active][value]=true;
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
    ->setSection('carriers')
    ->setWebsite(null)
    ->setStore($StoreId)
    ->setGroups($groups)
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   foreach (Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers() as $k => $carrier) {
       if ($carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) { // or your custom condition
           $options[] = array(
               'value' => $k,
               'label' => $carrier->getConfigData('title'),
           );
       }             
   }
   ```
2. To enable shipping methods you can update the config.