# oberserver event for filter shipment method

Tags: module, event-observer, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

can you please tell me which observer event i have to use for filter shipment method before shipment method load on onpage checkout ? and also code for how to acces a shipment method or return true or false.

i.e in below given code i can control which payment method i want i can show it or not on checkout page. even its enabled or disabled in magento admin so same thing i want with shipment method.

---

```
payment_method_is_active  

//i.e this observer and below given coe i used for control payement method visibility on one page checkout

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();


        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
       // echo $method->getCode()."<br>";
      //$result->isAvailable = true;
or 
       //$result->isAvailable = true;
}
}
```

So i want same thing with shipment method

Comment: please check this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/35914/20064

Comment: can you please help me about where i have to write that code? because i cant see any event suggest for that? i have to write it in observer or somewhere else